# How can I throttle a large array of async workflows passed to Async.Parallel

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have an array holding a large number of small async database queries; for example:

```
// I actually have a more complex function that
// accepts name/value pairs for query parameters.
let runSql connString sql = async {
    use connection = new SqlConnection(connString)
    use command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    do! connection.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
    return! command.ExecuteScalarAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    }

let getName (id:Guid) = async {
    // I actually use a parameterized query
    let querySql = "SELECT Name FROM Entities WHERE ID = '" + id.ToString() + "'"
    return! runSql connectionString querySql
    }

let ids : Guid array = getSixtyThousandIds()

let asyncWorkflows = ids |> Array.map getName
//...
```

Now, the problem: The next expression runs all 60K workflows at once, flooding the server.  This leads to many of the `SqlCommand`s timing out; it also typically causes out of memory exceptions in the client (which is F# interactive) for reasons I do not understand and (not needing to understand them) have not investigated:

```
//...
let names =
    asyncWorkflows
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I've written a rough-and-ready function to batch the requests:

```
let batch batchSize asyncs = async {
    let batches = asyncs
                  |> Seq.mapi (fun i a -> i, a)
                  |> Seq.groupBy (fst >> fun n -> n / batchSize)
                  |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.map snd)
                  |> Seq.map Async.Parallel
    let results = ref []
    for batch in batches do
        let! result = batch
        results := (result :: !results)
    return (!results |> List.rev |> Seq.collect id |> Array.ofSeq)
}
```

To use this function, I replace `Async.Parallel` with `batch 20` (or another integer value):

```
let names =
    asyncWorkflows
    |> batch 20
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This works reasonably well, but I would prefer to have a system that starts each new async as soon as one completes, so rather than successive batches of size N starting after each previous batch of size N has finished, I am always awaiting N active `SqlCommand`s (until I get to the end, of course).

Questions:

- Am I reinventing the wheel?  In other words, are there library functions that do this already?  (Would it be profitable to look into exploiting [ParallelEnumerable.WithDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd383719(v=vs.110).aspx) somehow?)
- If not, how should I implement a continuous queue instead of a series of discrete batches?

I am not primarily seeking suggestions to improve the existing code, but such suggestions will nonetheless be received with interest and gratitude.

Comment: This looks like a good fit for reactive streams.

Comment: Have you seen [“Throttled” async download in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6219726/636019)? [Scheduling with Async.Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27012651/636019)?

Comment: @ildjarn no, thank you for bringing those to my attention.  My searches did not find them.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin can you elaborate?  I am pulling the information from the database; my experience with reactive streams is in the context of push messages.

Comment: I was thinking I could write an answer using F# agents :) Thanks to @ildjarn for pointing out that I did exactly this twice already!

Comment: @ildjarn I just looked at those questions and their answers; I tried a solution with MailboxProcessor a couple of weeks ago but I couldn't quite get my head around it.  These helped immensely; thanks again.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thank you very much for the informative examples, even if they were posted to other questions ;-)

Comment: @phoog : Indeed, I have the questions for those answers favorited for a reason. ;-D

Comment: If you don't mind converting your asyncs to tasks, you could use ParallelQuery https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383736(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[`FSharpx.Control` offers an `Async.ParallelWithThrottle` function](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-async.html). I'm not sure if it is the best implementation as [it uses `SemaphoreSlim`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Async/Async.fs#L33). But the ease of use is great and since my application doesn't need top performance it works well enough for me. Although since it is a library if someone knows how to make it better it is always a nice thing to make libraries top performers out of the box so the rest of us can just use the code that works and just get our work done!

Answer (score 0):

[`Async.Parallel` had support for throttling added in FSharp v 4.7](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/improved-asynchronous-support-in-f-4-7/). You do:

```
let! results = Async.Parallel(workflows, maxDegreeOfParallelism = dop)
```

---

- [if doing more than 1200 workflows concurrently in `FSharp.Core` versions <= `6.0.5`, see this resolved issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/13165)
- [Proposal for a more explicit API](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq/issues/143)