# Throttled parallelism options in F#

Tags: f#

I want to use throttled parallelism when processing some data. There are the following options,

- Using .Net's blocking queue
- Tomas's BlockingQueueAgent, which is implemented using `MailboxProcessor`
- Using C# Task
- ....

Is there any other options? Espeically these Idiomatic F# approaches?

Comment: See [Scheduling with Async.Parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27012651/636019) and [“Throttled” async download in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6219726/636019)

Comment: Interesting, the first question is also answered by Tomas. How it compares to his BlockingQueueAgent?

Comment: I've used the [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) in c#, but not in f#. Unfortunately, f# async is not the same as c# Task and some translation is necessary. It is a beautiful thing that should really exist in the F# world as all of the 'blocks' are really functional constructs. These blocks take [ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides the throttling which you seek.

Comment: Looks like I keep writing the same answer over and over :-). I think the `ThrottlingAgent` answers are just direct answers to the specific problem while `BlockingQueueAgent` is a more general tool that can be used to implement the throttling pattern. Both would do the trick in the same way.

That said, if you can get away with just using standard .NET blocking queue, then that's probably the way to go - no code is always better than some code, even if its mine :)