# Asynchronous function calls in Parallel with throttle

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, queue, message-queue, throttling

I've attempted based on the suggestion but still having hiccups, can someone help out based on the attempt? My method signatures are different returning a Tuple and I need to return results to the caller (not just execution)

I've error in this line `do! work`

> > Error: The expression was expected to have type Result but here has type 'unit'

```
  type Error = {
    code : int
    message : string
  }

  /// Message type used by the agent - contains queueing
  /// of work items and notification of completion
  type internal ThrottlingAgentMessage =
    | Completed of Result<string, Error>
    | Enqueue of Async<Result<string, Error>>

  /// Represents an agent that runs operations in concurrently. When the number
  /// of concurrent operations exceeds 'limit', they are queued and processed later
  let throttlingAgent limit =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
      async {
        // The agent body is not executing in parallel,
        // so we can safely use mutable queue & counter
        let queue = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Async<Result<string, Error>>>()
        let running = ref 0

        while true do

          // Enqueue new work items or decrement the counter
          // of how many tasks are running in the background
          let! msg = inbox.Receive()
          match msg with
          | Completed r -> decr running
          | Enqueue w -> queue.Enqueue(w)

          // If we have less than limit & there is some work to
          // do, then start the work in the background!
          while running.Value < limit && queue.Count > 0 do
            let work = queue.Dequeue()
            incr running
            do! // When the work completes, send 'Completed'
                // back to the agent to free a slot
                async {
                  do! work
                  inbox.Post(Completed)
                }
                |> Async.StartChild
                |> Async.Ignore
      })

  let requestAsync (url: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
      async {
          Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
          try
              do! Async.Sleep(1000)
              return Ok (url + ":body...")
          with :? WebException as e ->
              return Error {code = 500; message = "Internal Server Error";}
      }

  let urls = [|
              "http://www.example.com/1";
              "http://www.example.com/2";
              "http://www.example.com/3";
              "http://www.example.com/4";
              "http://www.example.com/5";
              "http://www.example.com/6";
              "http://www.example.com/7";
              "http://www.example.com/8";
              "http://www.example.com/9";
          |]

  let w = throttlingAgent 3
  for url in urls do
    requestAsync url
    |> Enqueue
    |> w.Post
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduling with Async.Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012651/scheduling-with-async-parallel)

Comment: Hi Taylor, I'm going to attempt based on this and post with some edits for possible reviews, fixes please

Comment: I've problems with my specific signature `Async<Result<string, Error>>` while the solution has a different signature.

Comment: can you please review my attempt

Comment: @TaylorWood I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP is trying to modify the previous answer to do something a bit different.

Comment: Ah, this was a _totally_ different question when I marked it as a duplicate... see edits.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you tried to modify the agent so that the work items are not `Async<unit>`, i.e. operations that run and finish without returning a result, but instead, operations that actually return something. You could do that, but you'd have to decide what you want to do with the results.

In this case, I think it is easier to leave the agent as is and instead handle the collection of results at the end. For example, if you want  to collect them in a collection, you can just write:

```
let results = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<_>()
let w = throttlingAgent 3
for url in urls do
  async { 
    let! res = requestAsync url
    results.Add res } |> Enqueue |> w.Post
```

For completeness, this is using the following definition of the types and the agent:

```
type Error = {
  code : int
  message : string
}

/// Message type used by the agent - contains queueing
/// of work items and notification of completion
type ThrottlingAgentMessage =
  | Completed 
  | Enqueue of Async<unit>

/// Represents an agent that runs operations in concurrently. When the number
/// of concurrent operations exceeds 'limit', they are queued and processed later
let throttlingAgent limit =
  MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    async {
      // The agent body is not executing in parallel,
      // so we can safely use mutable queue & counter
      let queue = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Async<unit>>()
      let running = ref 0

      while true do

        // Enqueue new work items or decrement the counter
        // of how many tasks are running in the background
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        match msg with
        | Completed -> decr running
        | Enqueue w -> queue.Enqueue(w)

        // If we have less than limit & there is some work to
        // do, then start the work in the background!
        while running.Value < limit && queue.Count > 0 do
          let work = queue.Dequeue()
          incr running
          do! // When the work completes, send 'Completed'
              // back to the agent to free a slot
              async {
                do! work
                inbox.Post(Completed)
              }
              |> Async.StartChild
              |> Async.Ignore
    })

let requestAsync (url: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
    async {
        Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
        try
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            return Ok (url + ":body...")
        with :? WebException as e ->
            return Error {code = 500; message = "Internal Server Error";}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Question, is it a long running process? `while true do`. I'm going to test and work on this. If it's a continuously long running process then I need to further customize it to use it within the function when I need it.

Comment: It's not working, I ran the test, didn't see any console output `"Simulating request "` and `result (ConcurrentBag)` is empty. Kindly execute at your end.

Comment: @Developer11 You need to add some logic for waiting until all the individual operations are processed. If you run it (without waiting) then the concurrent bag is returned before the work items complete. If you run it from REPL, wait a bit and then look at the values, I think it should work...

Comment: Is there a possibility of building an async task around it so it actually wait for it to finish and then return values to the program. I’ve to use it in a program.

Comment: @Developer11 Yes, it's possible. But you shouldn't expect people here will write a complete solution for your.

Comment: I understand but I'm unable to wrap my head around it, I've done it differently using Queue in nodejs, any direction please

Comment: I just read something on delegate, is it with a callback an answer?

Comment: Hi Tomas, I'm still working on it and unable to find my way out, I need help and am blocked here